# Is there any command to make my tkinter labels splitted but still one label?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

Im talking about making my labels like connected buttons at the same width as normal one.
Second one I need to make is longer like two normal labels.
Here's an image how it has to look like. How can I make left upper corner labels and right lower corner label?

[image]

Do you have any idea? Any command? Searching in the website is not enough :(

Comment: use `grid` method, it has `columnspan` and `rowspan` arguments, definitely some docs cover this and likely there are multiple examples on this site and elsewhere

Comment: Ok, it worked, but I have a problem with label above those buttons, cuz it's not exactly above then but it's like pushed on the left. Can I change position in some way?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that exactly but I would guess that adding `sticky='news'` to the `grid` method would fix that (also the `grid` method has `padx` and `pady` arguments for padding)